# Mixed authentication for OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have two authenticate users in two ways:

1. If they are an internal user we authenticate through Windows' active directory
2. If they registered with the site they authenticate through Forms Authentication

In MVC 3/4 I was able to accomplish this by implementing a custom membership provider and custom role provider.

Is the same possible in MVC 5 using OWIN and Identity and how can it be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In essence a mixed mode is a forms authentication with a windows authentication entry point, once the user gets passed it, the normal forms authentication flow takes place.

> [Enabling Windows Authentication in Katana](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana)
>
> **Katana does not currently provide OWIN middleware for Windows Authentication, because this functionality is already available in the servers**

So for windows authentication to work, I have to rely on one of the provided hosts, either **IIS** or **Self-host (*System.Net.HttpListener*)**.

I made a solution that makes it **look like** an external provider, mapping windows identities as external logins.

[image: Mixed Authentication]

Source code : https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth

Comment: Say I want the same login screen for both authentication forms. Can your solution be modified to combine them into a single action. As a related question, can `Identity` be done using database-first for external users?

Comment: @Shoe I didn't get your point! The solution already have [one login screen](https://raw2.github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth/screens/screens/Login.PNG) for both (win+forms). 

but if you mean combining both to a single controller action? then yes it can be done, but for coding reasons I prefer keeping them separate.

as for your last question, you just need to implement your own `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and `UserStore<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: I Understand. In DB-first how would `User` class inherit from `IdentityUser` like `ApplicationUser` does?

Comment: @Shoe Its a matter of implementation, `IdentityUser` is just a base class, with clear mapping to DB tables. For a DB-first implementation all you need is just to implement a `UserStore`, it has a long list of interfaces, but you can start by looking at the EF implementation inside `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll`.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275597/how-to-give-custom-implementation-of-updateasync-method-of-asp-net-identity

Comment: @Learning Avoid using the UserStore directly and use the ApplicationUserManager instead.