# Adding ADFS authentication to a WebForms asp.net app

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, webforms, adfs3.0

My C# .net 4.5 asp.net app currently uses forms authentication. We need to implement SSO on it via an on-premises ADFS 3.0 server that will link to external ADFS servers using Claims Provider Trusts.

The thing is that some users will continue logging in the old Forms Auth way while others will be authenticating using their ADFS credentials.

Can ADFS and Forms Auth be mixed? How can I direct the different users to the different logins?

I read here that I might need to code my own Custom Auth Provider...this seems pretty complicated. Is there another simpler way?

Comment: Do you want all users to have to log in, or only some users who might not have AD credentials?  Are you using OWIN?

Comment: Only those users that don't have ADFS will need to login the old forms authentication way. And yes I use OWIN.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029192/mixed-authentication-for-owin

Comment: @Jared Dykstra, Thanks but this link explains how to implement Forms Auth on an MVC project... I need to add ADFS login to a WebForms project that already uses Forms Auth.

Comment: @zukanta have you found out any solution. I need to perform same. Please post answer if you have already solved